# How do I specify my toggle button to open for my menu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, menu, toggle

I am trying to make my mobile navigation open up when you click the toggle button (http://international-aset.com/intaset/); however for some reason it doesn't work when you click the button itself but it works when you click the SURROUNDING area of the button.

EDIT: What I am trying to do is make my navigation open up by clicking the toggle button, which would then enable the toggle animation. Right now, the toggle button works but my navigation doesn't open up when I click the button. The only time my navigation opens up is when I click the surrounding area (white space) around my toggle button.

I hope this makes more sense, if not please let me know and I will try my best to be more clear.

Here is the HTML code:

```
<label for="toggle">
  <div class="menu-icon-container">
    <a href="#" class="menu-toggle" id="menu-toggle"><span></span></a>
  </div>
</label>
```

Here is the JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $( document ).ready( function( $ ) {
    $('.menu-icon-container').on('click', function(event) {
      document.getElementById('menu-toggle').addEventListener('click', function() {
        this.classList.toggle('menu-toggle-active');
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: you're adding **TWO** click handlers. the first one just adds a click handler to the `menu-toggle` item, and it's THAT second handler which'll do your class toggling. so you need to click twice: once to add the real click handler, and then click again to trigger that real handler.

Comment: No need for `addEventListener` if you're using jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

You probably just want this:

```
$('#menu-toggle').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('menu-toggle-active');
});
```

You only really need `on()` if your element doesn't exist at page load. If you do in fact need it, do this:

```
$(document).on('click', '#menu-toggle', function() { ... });
```

Comment: This still doesn't work. I still need to click the surrounding area of the btn (div class=menu-icon-container) in order to open the navigation.

I want to be able to open the navigation by simply clicking the button NOT the surrounding aread

Comment: I don't see this on your site now. I see a hybrid of this and your earlier code.

Comment: Sorry, I removed it because it wasn't working. I will add it again now

Comment: I have updated it now. The code allows the toggle to animate but it doesn't open up the navigation unless I click around it

Comment: What's unclear in your question is what should change on click. Please clarify up there. I assumed you were simply toggling a class on the button, but apparently that's not right.

Comment: What I want to happen when I click the button is for the button to change (to X) and for it to open the navigation. And when I click the button again, I want the button to change back to the menu icon and for it to close my navigation. I hope this makes sense

Comment: I'm asking what variable, class, or element should be modified.

Comment: .menu-icon-container (opens the navigation when clicked)
menu-toggle (affects the toggle button to animate when activated)

Thank you so much for your help. I really appreciate it

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand. Please be more specific, i.e. "When I click `.menu-icon-container` I'd like to toggle the class `blah` on the element `.bloof`.

Answer (score 1):

try just adding `#menu-target` after your click event:

```
$('.menu-icon-container').on('click', function(event) {
    $("#menu-toggle").classList.toggle('menu-toggle-active');
});
```